# MODx обрезает параметры в URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache, modx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

MODx Revo, обрезаются любые параметры в url кроме page, то есть ссылка вида https://xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx/?page=2 работать будет, а вида https://xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx/?page=2&x=x уже не будет(MODx выдаёт "no_records_found")

.htaccess:

```html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://catalog.inoxpharm.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

# without www  all domian
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: `.htaccess` в данном случаи не причём (его вообще в принципе, в modx revo трогать надо очень редко) Как выводятся позиции (через какой сниппет?)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на сниппеты, действительно один из сниппетов обрабатывал параметры и все параметры, которые были в url применял в фильтр для выборки из БД